# Vue computed property that isn't referenced anywhere

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

#### Question

How do you create a dummy `computed` property which will get called when model elements it depends on change without having to said computed property?

#### Background

My parent is a number of form controls which set ajax query params.  When they change I need to fetch data form the server and then I `$emit` the new data to child components.

Initially, I had a `method` called `updateTable` that is invoked via `@change="updateTable()"` on each of the elements.

Didn't like needing to add @change to all my `input`'s so I created a dummy computed property to make use of the automatically dependency detection/recalculation.  The problem is Vue is "too" smart in my case since I don't actually reference the computed property anywhere. A workaround was to add `<div style="display:none">{{dummyProp}}</div>` but that seems hacky.

Is my pattern wrong? Or is there a better Vue way of doing this?

Comment: **which will get called when model elements it depends on change** this sounds like a watch.

Comment: > "I `$emit` the new data to child components." Yeah, this is probably the wrong pattern. Why are they not receiving props?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a `computed` generate the query parameter object. When form inputs change, the query parameter object gets updated. A watcher on that sends the ajax request, whose callback updates what I hope are props to the child components.

If your form elements are bound to variables, you shouldn't have been using `@change` anyway, you should have been watching the variables -- and you will be, since that's what a `computed` does.

Comment: That's a good idea... Have computed create the query data... and watch that variable alone.

Comment: One issue i'm encountering now is my computed property isn't triggering on load... I'm guessing in `mounted` i could modify a value that the computed property depends on but that seems hacky.

Comment: Just make the ajax call in `created` in addition to in your watcher.

Answer (score 1):

Your computed property doesn't need to be referenced by your HTML to stay reactive.  For instance, you can have:

```
data: {
  return {
    inputA: 'A',
    inputB: 'B'
  }
},
computed: {
  myProperty() {
    return this.inputA + this.inputB
  }
},
methods: {
  callWithMyProperty() {
    ajaxFunction(this.myProperty)
  }
}
```

Whenever you call `callWithMyProperty` with a pattern like this, it will use the latest versions of `inputA` and `inputB`.  I assume you are probably using a different (perhaps non-Vue) pattern and that is causing the issue.